# How could I get rid off border around header image

Tags: html, css

I created basic html and css webpage and in header element i put image,with 100% width margin:auto and it still exist some space between image and border of my screen.I am using Edge browser on my laptop with recent update.

Comment: Please provide your code so we can help find a solution.

Comment: You will have to provide, at minimum, a complete example of your code. Without this, no one can tell you what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're looking for `body { margin: 0; }`